# How to suppress irrelevant errors in a try block

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, try-catch

Suppose I want to check that a certain entry is in a Series.  I would like to try to access that entry, and if that fails, raise a simple, short ValueError.

For example, I have a series that doesn't have entry `C` - I want a check to halt the script.  Example:

```
s = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
s = pd.Series(s)

try:
    s['C']
except:
    raise ValueError('C is missing.')
```

But this code throws a long KeyError before spitting out the ValueError.  It works, but is verbose.

(I know that I can use an assert statement instaead.)

Why doesn't the try block suppress the KeyError - isn't that part of its purpose?  Is there a way to get my intended behavior?

Comment: Why do you want a `ValueError` to be raised for a missing key? Seems like `KeyError` is the correct exception here.

Comment: `if 'C' in s:` ?.

Comment: @MattDMo because probably the function this is in should raise a `ValueError` for good reasons. The fact that there is a key-error going on is an implementation detail. This is pretty normal.

Comment: @DeepSpace There is nothing wrong with using error handling, and indeed, it's the preferred approach

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not blindly. Sometimes exception handling has an overhead, especially if it is the path that will happen more often. Also, `try` block for just a side effect ("dummy" code used **only** to raise or not raise the exception) feels like a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing [exception chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exception-chaining). This extra information can be suppressed with a `from None` clause in your `raise` statement. Consider this (totally contrived) case where I am suppressing a `ZeroDivisionError` and raising a `KeyError`:

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     raise KeyError
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
KeyError
```

But if I use `from none`:

```
>>> try:
...     1/0
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     raise KeyError from None
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
KeyError
>>>
```

Also note, you **really should not use a bare `except` clause**. Catch as specific an error as possible.